# Wordpress pages redirecting to Home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website at http://www.wjewel.com/ . All the pages of the website are getting redirected to home page. There is no .htaccess file or web.config file for redirections. Can someone please guide me what could be the reason for this issue.

Comment: Check for plugin for redirect

Comment: check your menu item in appearance-> menus-> custom links

Comment: I have open the page in edit and tried to view from there .. That also didn't work.. Before downvoting, and if you think this is an easy quesiton, let me know the answer pls

Answer (score 6):

Resetting the permalinks within WordPress will resolve this issue.

To reset the permalinks for your WordPress installation:

- Log into the WordPress Dashboard.
- In the side panel, go to Settings > Permalinks.
- Make note of the current setting. (If you are using a custom
  structure, copy or save the custom structure somewhere.)
- Select the Default option.
- Click Save Changes.
- Now select the previous setting you had before Default was selected.
- Click Save Changes.

Comment: I have tried that already and again after you answered.. That didn't work.

Comment: Please put a wordpress default htaccess file on root, that is also a solution, may that will work for you.

Comment: I have hosted this in a windows environment. I guess .htaccess wont work. can you suggest me a web.config file pls

Comment: please check this, this will help you- https://solutions.hostmysite.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/8793/278/wordpress-webconfig-file-for-windows

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I have used the same code. seems to be working now. but /blog link is still not working

Comment: It's Great @Phani

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is done on client side. You have this meta tag in the `html head`.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.wjewel.com">
```

(It has nothing to do with PHP headers)

I'd try to look for plugins injecting that meta tag or theme header.

Also just an observation - `html body` on **/about/** page (for example) is empty.

Comment: where can I find this code. I can't see in header.php file in appearences -> editor

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam.. It seems to be working after placing web.config file.

Comment: HTML code of /about/ page seems very odd in comparison to the rest of the site. Try looking for /about/ folder in your www root and if it contains index.html. My guess is the pages redirecting back to homepage aren't wordpress generated.

Comment: @Phani glad to hear that. You might specify the source of problem and solution for future usage.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and found that Yoast SEO have a permalinks setting which had two of my pages listed as redirect to home page.

I don't recall myself setting them up, but **thankfully** there was a button to delete those pages from that list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I had the same issue and tried all solutions with no luck. Even deleting htaccess didn't work. I changed my settings to set latest posts as my homepage and then changed it to the desired page and that did the trick (at least for now)

Answer (score 0):

> fixed

I had a similar problem.

But only some selected pages were redirecting to home. And these pages which were redirecting worked on page no. permalink setting.

Tried everything as mentioned above, nothing worked.

I cleared my browser cache and it was all good again.

Comment: I didn't clear my cache but I swapped from Safari to Chrome and it worked so maybe there's something client-side and not server-side.