# All pages and posts in Wordpress redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've been having this problem a couple times now and I'm not sure what is causing it. I have tried disabling all plugins, resetting permalinks, and resetting to the default .htacccess file but this time I seem to not be able to fix this issue.

Whenever I try to visit any post or page, instead of displaying a post at /post-name/ it displays a list of my latest posts.

I thought I read about the publishing dates affecting this once but I'm not sure.

Any help you could provide would be awesome!

edit: I've installed and activated a different theme and it did not solve the problem. I still see a list of lastest posts on every page/post.

Comment: did you maybe change the "permalink" setting in the wordpress settings (has to be set to "post name")? Your links are all okay, but maybe the site doesn't recognize them due to another permalink setting and redirects all links to the homepage?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, I changed the permalink setting to 'post name' and is what it always has been.

Comment: not sure what that means - good or bad?

Comment: Is there a `single.php` and/or `singular.php` file in your theme?

Comment: @belinus Yes, single.php:

Comment: @Johannes Nothing changes when changing the permalink settings and it's normally set to page name

Comment: Can you post the code for it somewhere like on Pastebin?

Comment: @belinus http://pastebin.com/gjbYvQ3k

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me there. Do you know the post ID of a published post? If so go to your site and append `?p={id}`

Comment: @belinus When I do that I get redirected to a url with the page name. However, I'm still only seeing the latest posts.

Comment: Something might be up with your `.htaccess` file then.

Comment: @belinus As I said before, I replaced .htaccess with the default Wordpress .htaccess file.

Comment: And you did that with all plugins disabled?

Comment: @belinus yes, I disabled all plugins. I'm about to restore a backup from a month ago, but I'll be doing some work to restore all the posts I had In the last month.

Comment: Backup what you have now and compare the templates and see what the code difference is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress pages redirecting to Home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344962/wordpress-pages-redirecting-to-home-page)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Yoast SEO plugin enabled, try deactivating it or making sure there are no links with permanent 301 redirects to Home